# Browser with fixed computed width

Tags: html, css, browser

I want to test my media-queries, but my browser doesn’t shrink the width even when I change it, examples below:

Moto G4 screen appears with a fixed width of 980px:

[image]

The same when I test with any other device screen:

[image]

Does someone know why is that happening?

Note: The problem is not the code at all, you know? It's like, I commented all the lines of my html, no css applied, no tags, nothing, and when I open it in the browser the fixed width remains.

Note 2: Funny thing is that when I create any other HTML file, the same problem happens, but when I create a react project it doesn't. So it's not the browser as well, is there some meta tag or anything of the kind that I'm grossly forgetting?

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I just forgot the most trivial thing of a HTML file, the initial meta tags, maybe it's due to so many time programming in React LOL

Comment: Those screenshots are too tiny to see the numbers. Can you please share the media queries you are using? If you add a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it will increase the chance of getting help.

Comment: Oh man, I didn't post any code because it doesn't matter whether there's any code on media queries or not, even because the code was just a line changing the margin to 0.

Comment: An extra pair of eyes looking at code couldn't hurt. Sometimes it's the little things that get us, like a semi-colon. Showing what you've done so far is a good start to see where to go from there.

Comment: The problem is not the code at all, you know? It's like, I commented all the lines of my html, no css applied, no tags, nothing, and when I open it in the browser the fixed width remains.

Comment: There's no real way to help without code. Have you tried a different browser, testing on a mobile device, or restarting your computer? This is as far as one can ask without checking the source.

Comment: I created a new file with nothing, and just opened it in the browser, the problem remained, how is the problem on the code if there's no code, you know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232365/discussion-between-levi-ermonaites-de-freitas-and-rawnewdlz).